# What does TIR stand for in Window Pane Fenestration?

Tags: glass, solar

When looking at glazings within various public databases I see the fields "tir" shown often. E.g as seen below:

```
"glazing_data": {
        ...
        "tir_front": 0.0,
        "tir_back": null,
        ...
    }
```

What does this field stand for?

Comment: Is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection?

Comment: That was my first thought but I dismissed it as it never applies to glazing because we never use it in that mode (looking through the edge of the glass). The air-glass-air refraction can't generate total internal refraction - unless the gasses are different on each side of the window. Post a link.

Comment: Could you point us to the database you got this example from?

Comment: Have you considered: thermal infrared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIR: Thermal infrared (longwave) transmittance of the glazing layer.

Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory has a windows program called THERM 6.3 / WINDOW 6.3
NFRC Simulation.

In pp 55 of this manual, there is a table referencing some properties of the glazing, including this.

[image: pp 55]

here is the [Therm 6.3 prog dowmload.](https://cdn.ymaws.com/www.nfrccommunity.org/resource/resmgr/technical_documents/nfrcsim6.3-2011-12-manual.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. The data was from IGDB too